# Custom ActionBar formy nativescript-vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm trying to make a custom ActionBar for my nativescript-vue app, I'm using FlexBoxLayout inside ActionBar but it's not working, the bars icon and title should be aligned to the left but they are centered ...

My code:

```
<Page style="background-color:rgb(245,245,245);">
    <ActionBar>
        <FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blue;  flex-direction:row; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center;">
            <Label text="Pacome" fontSize="24" />
        </FlexboxLayout >
    </ActionBar>
     <FlexboxLayout style="flex-direction:column; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background-color:rgb(245,245,245);">
        <!--<FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:90px; padding:20px; background-color:blue; flex-direction:row; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center;">
            <Label :text="'fa-facebook-f' | fonticon" class="fa-brands icon" style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;"/>
            <Label :text="'fa-bars' | fonticon" class="fa c_light" style="font-size:25; margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;"/>
            <Label class="c_light" text="Pacome" style="font-size:25;" />
        </FlexboxLayout >
        <Label class="c_normal" text="Pacomer" style="font-size:25;" />-->
    </FlexboxLayout >
</Page>
```

Comment: Try applying `horizontalAlignment="left"` on the `FlexboxLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blue;  flex-direction:row; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:center;">
```

to this:

```
<FlexboxLayout style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:blue;  flex-direction:row; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:flex-start;">
```

You can also try `text-align:left`.

Here is some helpful diagrams about flex align items: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/